# Fill diagonals of a square matrix in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to learn it. I have been trying to make a simple script in which you input a number n that represents the number of rows and columns of a matrix. After that the matrix should have on the diagonals "*" and on the edges "#" the rest are empty spaces.
I have been trying things like this but it doesn't really work:

```
my_list=[]
n=int(input("please enter the number of lines and columns: "))
my_list[0][0:n-1]="#"
my_list[n-1][0:n-1]="#"
my_list[0:n-1][0]="#"
my_list[0:n-1][n-1]="#"
my_list[i in range(1,n-2)][j in range(1,n-2)]="*"
print (my_list)
```

i would like it to look like this:

```
n=5
#####
#* *#
# * #
#* *#
#####
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

P.S. I tried to search online for a solution a lot but a lot of people are using numpy I would like to do it vanilla so that I can learn the basics first.

Comment: python list assignment does not work like numpy assignment. `my_list[0:n-1][0]` does not select the "first column", it is the same as `my_list[0]` which selects the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating a list like a numpy array and trying to assign multiple slices at a time. To keep things simple, just create an empty NxN list and fill out the cells you need in a symmetric fashion.

```
n = 5
my_list = [[' ' for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    my_list[i][i]    = '*'     # primary diagonal
    my_list[i][-i-1] = '*'     # secondary diagonal  

    my_list[0][i]    = '#'     # first row
    my_list[-1][i]   = '#'     # last row
    my_list[i][0]    = '#'     # first column
    my_list[i][-1]   = '#'     # last column
```

```
for l in my_list: print(*l, sep='')
#####
#* *#
# * #
#* *#
#####
```

---

This is the output at each iteration.

```
#   #
     
     
     
#
```

```
##  #
#* *#
     
     
##
```

```
### #
#* *#
# * #
     
###
```

```
#####
#* *#
# * #
#* *#
####
```

```
#####
#* *#
# * #
#* *#
#####
```